# How to change property in tree-like group of objects?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a list of department ids which I use to get their subjects.
I'd like to group these subjects by *department title path*.
For example, let's imagine that we have three departments: Office, Room1, Room2. Office is a parent of Room1 and Room2 so I wanna see smth like this: "Office", "Office/Room1", "Office/Room2".

Let's see my code:

```
var departmentsIds = _parameters.ShowSubjectsOfNestedDepartments
      ? await GetDepartmentsIdsWithNested()
      : _parameters.DepartmentIDs;
```

```
var groupedSubjects = ( await _subjectClient
      .GetByDepartmentsIds( departmentsIds )
      .Unwrap() )
      .GroupBy( subject => subject.Department.Title );
```

I got subject by departments ids and than I just grouped by Department.Title.

`groupedSubjects` is just a list of `SubjectDto`:

```
public class SubjectDto
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public DepartmentDigestDto Department { get; set; }
}

public class DepartmentDigestDto
{
    [JsonProperty( PropertyName = "id" )]
    [JsonRequired]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty( PropertyName = "title" )]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty( PropertyName = "parent_department_id" )]
    public string ParentDepartmentId { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone explain me how to change groupedSubjects key based on what I said earlier, please?

Comment: You can write recursive function for each element, where fill it parents. Standard practice.

Comment: smth like: .GroupBy(subject => SomeRecursiveFunction(subject)); ?

Comment: yes, if you want to use linq in this case

Comment: hm, interesting.. but how should I group subjects in recursive function? May you give me 1 example, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try recursive function, something like that:

```
class Dto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dto? Parent { get; set; }
}
// it's just an example, need to make it works OK for your case
public void GetDtoRecursive()
{
    List<Dto> dtos = new List<Dto>(); // some collection
    foreach (var dto in dtos) {
        FillDto(dto);
    }

    void FillDto(Dto dto) {
        if (dto.ParentId == null)
            return;
        dto.Parent = dtos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == dto.ParentId);
        if (dto.Parent != null)
            FillDto(dto.Parent); // recursive call
    }
}
```